# Networking issue in Windows 8.1 / 7 and Virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, vpn, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 (x64) installed on my notebook PC, I've also installed a Windows 7 (x86) in Virtual Box which is installed in my Windows 8.1. in Windows 8.1 I can access a network that is not internet accessible but I can access Internet through a VPN that in install in Windows 7, Note that I CAN NOT access Internet by the same VPN in Windows 8.1, So I have to use Windows 7 and its VPN to access the Internet.

Please consider the following scheme, In that, Interfaces 1,5 is in Windows 8.1 and 2,3,4 in Windows 7, When I start VPN in Windows 7 it uses Interface 2 and connect to internet successfully (So Windows 7 has access to Internet).

What I want to accomplish is I want to make Windows 8.1 to access Internet through local interfaces 4,5. I've updated route table of Windows 8.1 in order to all outcome traffic will direct to interface 5 (I've set default gateway to be interface 5). So far every things is OK and no problem raised, But in Windows 7 I need a tool/software/trick/or something else that bridge traffics between interface 4 and 3.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: I want to be sure i am understanding you right, you want 8.1 to access the internet through 7 which connects through your wifi?

Comment: @AndrewCrawford yes

Comment: That will be pretty hard because you need to disable the wifi on win 8.1 but doing so will stop win7 getting online it might take me awhile to work this out

Comment: @AndrewCrawford why disabling WiFi in win 8.1 ? I can manipulate its routing table in order to all traffic will be directed to interface 5

Comment: even with the routing table manipulated it will still use the connection  you have to set it such the wifi i invisible to windows 8.1 as a connection but still there as connection for virtualbox, if you want to try play with the routing tables i can probably work out the configuration for the rest quicker but i can't guarantee it will work the way you want it